# How to display optional fields in @incollection?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, texworks

I'm using the amsart class and I have the following entry in Bibtex:

```
@incollection{GrSw97a,
   title={The Maximum Principle and Positive Principal Eigenfunctions for Polyharmonic Equations},
  booktitle={Reaction Diffusion Systems},
  author={Grunau, H. C. and Sweers, G.},
volume={194},
pages={163--182},
  isbn={9780824701253},
  lccn={97035931},
  series={Lecture Notes in Pure and Applied Mathematics},
  year={1997},
PUBLISHER = {Dekker},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
}
```

which is printed as:

> H. C. Grunau and G. Sweers, The maximum principle and positive principal eigenfunctions for polyharmonic
> equations, Reaction diffusion systems, 1997, pp. 163–182.

As you can see, the name of the series, its volume, etc. is missing. How can I get it in the following way?

> H. C. Grunau, G. Sweers, The maximum principle and positive principal eigenfunctions for polyharmonic equations, in Reaction Diffusion Systems, in Lecture Notes in Pure and Applied Mathematics, vol.194, Dekker, New York, 1997, pp.163–182.

I haven't specified any bibliography style.

Comment: You have a much better chance of getting a good answer here if you add a short example document that shows your current bibliography setup to the question. So far we only know which document class you use and nothing else about how you create citations and bibliographies. There are several different way of producing bibliographies and a solution to your question will depend on the way you chose. The best way to show us what you have so far is via a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: That said, if your document/template uses a BibTeX style (still by far the most common method), the changes your are looking for will require some changes to the `.bst` file, which uses quite an unusual programming language.